# The mapped list is not saved to the database with the entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

The mapped list is not saved. I set the values for the `MovieDescription` entity, then adds that entityto the `MovieEntity` entity list and saves it to the database. However, the `MovieDescription` entity does not save.

I have the main entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies")
@Data
public class MovieEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    ....

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<MovieDescription> descriptions;
}
```

Then I have an entity

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
public class MovieInfo {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private MovieEntity movie;

    @ManyToOne
    private UserEntity user;

    private EditStatus status;

    private Integer points;
}
```

and then I have description entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class MovieDescription extends MovieInfo {

    private String description;
}
```

Then I try to save the movie to the base

```
@Override
public void createMovie(
        @NotNull @Valid final MovieDTO movieDTO,
        @Min(1) final Long userId
) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    final UserEntity user = this.userRepository.findByIdAndEnabledTrue(userId).get();

    final MovieEntity movie = new MovieEntity();
    movie.setStatus(EditStatus.WAITING);
    movie.setTitle(movieDTO.getTitle());
    movie.setType(movieDTO.getType());
    movieDTO.getDescription().ifPresent(description -> {
        MovieDescription movieDescription = new MovieDescription();
        movieDescription.setDescription(description);
        movieDescription.setUser(user);
        movieDescription.setStatus(EditStatus.WAITING);
        movie.getDescriptions().add(movieDescription);
        System.out.println(movieDescription);
    });
    this.movieRepository.save(movie)
```

Comment: Any error message is thrown?

Comment: Nothing throws. No problem recording. Then I go to the database and there is no.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to:

`movieDescription.setMovie(movie)`

Comment: So I have to save the movie and description separately?

Comment: No, you don't have to, it will be saved automatically since you have `CascadeType.ALL`. If you mean if 2 insert queries will be generated then yes, there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

so the best way to do that is to have a convenience method in MovieEntity class, which will make your code look clean and you won't forget to set the reference to the bidirectional way.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies")
@Data
public class MovieEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    ....

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<MovieDescription> descriptions;

    public void addMovieDescription(MovieDescription movieDescription){
         movieDescription.setMovie(this);
         descriptions.add(movieDescription);
    }
}
```